# ASP.NET - setting status code in controller response

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a little bit confused sending specific status codes in responses from Web API controllers. Here is example of a simple controller method:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetDeliveryMethods()
    {
        if (AuthenticationControl)
        {                
            return Ok(db.DeliveryMethods);
        }
        else
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
```

Well, "AuthenticationControl" represents some procedure checking, if a client can get data from the server. Whole method works well, but when I get back a response from the server status code is always 200 OK. 
I don't understand why, this declaration of responses and status codes is also in main controller template in VS.

What I have to do to send my declaration of status code in response?

Comment: It seems like you're asking why this code always returns 200. Have you considered placing a breakpoint and confirming that it actually hits the `return StatusCode()`?

Comment: Yes, but when I set response to "BadRequest: or "NotFound", status code is changed. So problem may be in declaration of the last line in code, that is no changing code number.

Comment: I have also tried to change last line just to "Unauthorized()", but no effect.

Comment: I am not sure what did you use in AuthenticationControl
but you could have  a class 
like  public class InfoModule : IHttpModule which gets the context and do the calculation base d on your business logic

var context = HttpContext.Current;

then based on your business rules return  context.Response.Status

then GetDeliveryMethods do your thing based on status of Response 
hope useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return HTTPResoponse instead of your current return type.

This allows you to set HTTP status codes